# Auto check saved data in jQuery Multiselect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, multi-select, bootstrap-multiselect

I am using this jQuery Multiselect plugin https://github.com/nobleclem/jQuery-MultiSelect to convert all my select boxes that have the multiple attribute enabled in to drop down boxes with check boxes. 
I load the options in the select box from a database.
Upon the form submission I can save the multiple selected data, but when I retreive data back from the database I cannot display the saved data back in the multi select box by checking matching check boxes.

The multiselect plugin has a `loadOptions` method, but using that method I have to generate all option data with option name, option value and the check status, and set it to the multiselect plugin. How can I easily do this if I have an array of data which must be checked/selected in the multiple select plugin?

**HTML**

```
<select name="abc" id="abc" multiple title="Test Number?">
    <option value="1">Test 1</option>
    <option value="2">Test 2</option>
    <option value="3">Test 3</option>
    <option value="4">Test 4</option>
    <option value="5">Test 5</option>
</select>
```

**JS** (I have more than one multiple select boxes and initiate them as shown below)

```
$.each($("select[multiple]"), function (key, selectbox) {
    $("#" + selectbox.id).multiselect({
        texts: {placeholder: $("#" + selectbox.id).attr("title")}
    });
});
```

My saved data array is `[1,3,4]`
I need to set these saved data to the select box and check the check boxes without going through the `loadOptions` method.

Comment: If the the options have `selected` attribute is it not working? Can you create a **working** [snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use jQuery [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) function on your `select` `options` to preselect those wanted before initializing the `multiselect` plugin.

Here,

```
$('option',this).filter((_,e) => saved_data.includes(+e.value)).prop('selected',true);
```

Preselects every option, before the `.multiselect()` call.

```js
let saved_data = [1, 3, 4];

$('select[multiple]').each(function() {
  $('option', this).filter((_, e) => saved_data.includes(+e.value)).prop('selected', true);

  $(this).multiselect({
    texts: {
      placeholder: $(this).attr("title")
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://springstubbe.us/projects/demos/jquery-multiselect/scripts/index.js?1523890673"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://springstubbe.us/projects/demos/jquery-multiselect/styles/index.css?1518818712">

<select name="abc" id="abc" multiple title="Test Number?">
  <option value="1">Test 1</option>
  <option value="2">Test 2</option>
  <option value="3">Test 3</option>
  <option value="4">Test 4</option>
  <option value="5">Test 5</option>
</select>
```